# SilverStripe arithmetic in template

Tags: silverstripe, arithmetic-expressions

I want to do a simple arithmetic operation in a .ss template.

```
<% loop $Images %>
    <img src="$Link" alt=""/>
    <% $Pos == 4 %>
        and {$TotalItems - 4} more foto's 
        $Break
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

For example I would want to output

> and 10 more foto's

But the best I can get is

> and 14 - 4 more foto's

I know I can make a function, which works for now, but can I do arithmetic operations in the template?

Comment: Well it worked, but thats not realy arithmetic. So thumbs up for workaround. @csy_dot_io

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this.

At first you limit the images to the amount you would like to display. After that you loop over the same set with an offset of x (4) and check if there's more. If so, output the amount of remaining images.

```
<% loop $Images.Limit(4,0) %>
   <img src="$Link" alt=""/>
<% end_loop %>
<% if $Images.Limit(9999,4) %>
  and $Images.Limit(9999,4).Count more foto's 
<% end_if %>
```

the code is untested but should work.

**Edit**

I think "real" arithmetic is not possible by default. You'll need to write a custom function to do this.